# Declaring variables inside mutate

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to declare the variables inside mutate using `all_of` but not getting proper output

```
asd <- data.frame(Col1 = c("A","B"), Col2 = c("R","E"))
a1 <- "Col1"
```

When I perform below operations, I get invalid output

```
asd %>% mutate(q1 = case_when(all_of(a1) == "A" ~ 1))
  Col1 Col2 a1
1    A    R NA
2    B    E NA
```

Expected Output

```
asd %>% mutate(q1 = case_when(Col1 == "A" ~ 1))
  Col1 Col2 q1
1    A    R  1
2    B    E NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Or we could use `glue::glue` just bear in mind that whatever you put inside curly braces will be evaluate as R code:

```
library(glue)

asd %>%
  mutate(q1 = case_when(
    eval(parse(text = glue("{a1}"))) == "A" ~ 1
  ))

  Col1 Col2 q1
1    A    R  1
2    B    E NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in `get()`

```
R> asd %>% mutate(q1 = case_when(all_of(get(a1)) == "A" ~ 1))
```

```
  Col1 Col2 q1
1    A    R  1
2    B    E NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `across`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
asd %>% 
   mutate(across(all_of(a1), ~ case_when(. == 'A' ~ 1),
    .names = "{str_replace(.col, '.*', 'q1')}"))
  Col1 Col2 q1
1    A    R  1
2    B    E NA
```